# Redirect 410 using a RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

It is possible to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.fr
RewriteRule ^linktopage.html$ [NC,R=410,L]
```

The thing is, the URL is the same for .fr and .es, for example, but i want to do a 410 only in the .fr domain but still be accessible in the .es domain

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.fr
RewriteRule ^linktopage.html$ - [G]
```

We are using gone flag.